# Sharing JWT Authentication/Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, authorization, webapi

Greetings programming community.

Here's something that I've been looking for but at the moment I don't believe I've had a straightforward answer.

Inside the same Solution I've got a JWT authentication webapi and a standard webAPi that returns random values.

How can I assure that the random values web api only responds when the user has a valid authorization that has been given by the jwt authenticaton webapi?

thank you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to do that:

1. Write a custom authorization filter and register for random-number-generator api, and intercept the requests: Catch the JWT per request and forward to the auth-api to ensure that it's valid and not expired yet.
2. Put both of apis behind an api-gateway like Nginx, Envoy, Ocelot (or something else) with jwt-handling-feature enabled. First catch the request on the gateway on ask for authorization/authentication from jwt-api. If the answer is true/OK, the request will automatically be forwarded to random-number-generator api.

**NOTE: In the second solution you will never be concerned about authentication/authorization in your random-number-gen api and you can freely develop your business behind the secure gateway.**

Comment: solution no 1 seems to be the path I want to choose. Any hints on how to go about implementing that ?

Comment: Yes dear, You can use this link to implement authorization filters if you are on dotnet-core platform:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#implementation
And you can send a http requests to your jwt-auth api in the implmented fitler:
http://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/

Comment: will that work with my example? ie: I will run the authentication in a separate jwt webapi. How do I check if the user that's trying to access the "random-number-gen api" has the correct credentials and is authorized?

Comment: Dear you should send a http request from the Random-Gen to your Jwt-api and pass the Jwt to that to check its identity and validity.

Comment: thank you sir. Took me a little while to get there but finally got it!

Comment: Glad to here that my dear :)